# WPS connection programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager, wps

how i can try a connection to a wifi with WPS protocol programmatically?
I have found how connect with WEP, WPA and open wifi, but not WPS...

Thanks all!

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER OF Greg432**

I have try this code but it don't work, solution?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                wpsInfo = new WpsInfo();
                wpsInfo.BSSID = wifiList.get(0).BSSID;
                wpsInfo.pin = "11883737";
                wpsInfo.setup = 0;


                wpsCallback = new WifiManager.WpsCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStarted(String pin) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started wps connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSucceeded() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailed(int reason) {
                        String errorMessage;
                        switch (reason) {
                            case WifiManager.WPS_OVERLAP_ERROR:
                                errorMessage = "WPS_OVERLAP_ERROR";
                                break;
                            case WifiManager.WPS_WEP_PROHIBITED:
                                errorMessage = "WPS_WEP_PROHIBITED";
                                break;
                            case WifiManager.WPS_TKIP_ONLY_PROHIBITED:
                                errorMessage = "WPS_WEP_PROHIBITED";
                                break;
                            /*case WifiManager.IN_PROGRESS:
                                mWifiManager.cancelWps(null);
                                startWps();
                                return;*/
                            case WifiManager.WPS_TIMED_OUT:
                                errorMessage = "WPS_TIMED_OUT";
                                //startWps();
                                return;
                            default:
                                errorMessage = "Generic error.";
                                break;
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };

                wifiManager.startWps(wpsInfo, wpsCallback);
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the WifiManager's startWps() method:

```
mWifiManager.startWps(wpsConfig, mWpsCallback);
```

You should pass a configuration and a callback.

Example

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TvSettings/+/lollipop-wear-release/Settings/src/com/android/tv/settings/connectivity/WpsConnectionActivity.java

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer, i have try to write a code, but don' t work fine... can you watch it?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2021**

Connecting with WPS programatically is deprecated and removed as of API 28 and above.

It is no longer possible to connect with `mWifiManager.startWps(wpsConfig, mWpsCallback);` And there are also no alternatives.

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#startWps(android.net.wifi.WpsInfo,%20android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WpsCallback)